# How can I destroy a CountDownTimer in Android?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have this code in a BroadcastReceiver that should change a textview with the word "CHARGING" if the phone is plugged or with a Count Down Timer if it is not:

```
       int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;


        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


            String str = Boolean.toString(isCharging);
            textView2.setText(str);


            CountDownTimer aCounter = new CountDownTimer((long) timeleft, 1000) {
                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

                       mTextField.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600,
                                (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60)));
                     }

                     public void onFinish() {
                         mTextField.setText("done!");
                     }
                  };


                if (usbCharge || acCharge ) {


                    textView3.setText("Charging");
                    mTextField.setText("CHARGING");


                        aCounter.cancel();
                        aCounter = null;


                }

                else {

                    textView3.setText("Not Charging");
                    mTextField.setText("NOT CHARGING");


                    aCounter.start();

                     }

                }
```

My problem is if I start the app with the phone plugged I can see the word "CHARGING" in the textview, when I unplug the phone I can see the count down timer, but when I plug the phone again, I only see the word "Charging" a millisecond and then I see the count down timer again. And if I unplug the phone again, I see two count down timers at the same time in the same textview.

It is like I create a new count down timer every time I plug the phone without destroy the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Oh ok, first of all, don't make CountDownTimer class like that

/* Declare a class level object */

```
private MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;

private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture,
                long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //TODO some code here

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

then when you want to start countdown timer

```
myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(
                999999999999999999L, 15 * 1000);

myCountDownTimer.start();
```

and when you want to cancel that

```
if(myCountDownTimer!=null)
{

    myCountDownTimer.cancel();

}
```

Comment: your timer is not cancelled?

Comment: you have to make a class level object of CountDownTimer then only you can close when next time it come on onReceive.

Comment: I m having the same issue, its like nobody have seen that before and no patches that correct this unexpected behavior (I wouldn't call it a bug), I ll use some other mechanisme like a chrono or something

Comment: It worked for me. Even when i don't declared a separate class file for CountDownTimer implementation, i do store it in my Activity class variable (as a property) in the next way:
`
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`
``
`    TextView txtTimer;`
`   CountDownTimer cntDwnTmr;`
``
`public void timerBtnClick(View v) {`
`        if(cntDwnTmr != null)`
`            cntDwnTmr.cancel();`
`        cntDwnTmr = new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 1, 1000 * 1) {`
`    .... //Methods implementation`
`}.start();`

Comment: @MohdMufiz Thanks, you save my time